# How to align custom NavigationView with custom menu items layout to the most left

Tags: android, layout, menu, navigationview

I need to make the items from menu (Navigation Drawer with full width) left aligned with their icons with the tittle text under that and each item should be in a square wrapping its content, so the items together would be like a tower left aligned. Because that I made a custom layout xml for them.

But I can't make the custom layout I made for the menu items to align on the most left of the screen. (The menu drawer opens from right to left).
My activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="172dp"
                android:background="@drawable/my_custom_background"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/icon"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Line 1"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                    android:text="Line 2"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Your_custom_menu_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="start|top"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layoutDirection="rtl"
              android:background="@drawable/border_set"
              android:padding="10dip">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        android:text="your_text"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="9dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main_drawer.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layoutDirection="ltr">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title=""
            app:showAsAction="never"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/your_custom_menu_layout"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title=""
            app:showAsAction="never"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/your_custom_menu_layout"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow"
            app:showAsAction="always"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/your_custom_menu_layout"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools"
            app:showAsAction="always"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/your_custom_menu_layout"/>
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share"
                app:actionLayout="@layout/your_custom_menu_layout"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send"
                app:actionLayout="@layout/your_custom_menu_layout"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

[What I get:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RCbo.png)

[What I need:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Refz.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your Your_custom_menu_layout.xml ,

In Parent Linear Layout Remove

```
android:padding="10dip"
```

It will give 10 dp padding from all the sides. So only you are not able to see your TextView. Once you remove this, You can get desired result. All the best.

Comment: Yes, thank you Ajith. The text is showed now.
But I still need to align the list on the most left corner.

Comment: Welcome. All the best.